# Outlook Add In debug no longer works after uninstalling Click Once installation

Tags: visual-studio, outlook, ms-office, outlook-addin

I am developing an Outlook 2016 plugin in visual studio. Up until this point, pressing debug in VS would open up Outlook and I could debug perfectly.

I recently published the plugin (using Click Once) and installed it on the same machine to test before sending to client.

I need to do some more development today, pressed debug, but then got an error that the plugin could not be upgraded and to uninstall it.

I uninstalled the plugin.

Now, when I press debug, Outlook opens but the Add In no longer shows up in Outlook.

How can I resume normal development flow after uninstalling the plugin?

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

after uninstalling the plugin you just need to "Clean Solution" from Build menu, then you can continue to debug.

[More info in answer found on Microsoft forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/3a4df2c2-7982-4d0a-a9b0-e87f5739d0cd/outlook-add-in-debug-no-longer-works-after-uninstalling-click-once-installation?forum=outlookdev)

Hope I helped.

Comment: It should be a comment not an answer.